# Retrieve list of ALL guests for a calendar event using Google Apps scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am using the below code to get the guest lists. While the code is running fine, it does not return ALL the guests. In fact, its showing very few of them. Is there any limitation of the function `getGuestList`? I looked at the documentation but it does mention any limitations.

```
for (var i = 0; i < unique_events_list.length; i++){
    var id = unique_events_list[i];
    var event = CalendarApp.getEventById(id);
    var event_title = event.getTitle().toString().toUpperCase().trim();
    //  get guest list
    var guestList = event.getGuestList(true);
    guestList.forEach(function(guest){
      invitees.push([event_title,guest.getEmail()]);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation, for example, in your situation, are the groups included in the guests?

Comment: @Tanaike ,Yes, groups are also included along with individual emails

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. You said `Yes, groups are also included along with individual emails`. But, from `Sorry, what I meant was that guestList only returns 5 emails instead of 18 that I can see on calendar, none of the 5 emails have googlegroups.com`, the groups are not included. In this case, my answer was not useful for your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: Based on the comments above, I understand that you have 18 guests in your calendar event but only get 5 when retrieving the list through Apps Script? The emails that you don't see through Apps Script, are these emails from a group or just regular email addresses? I just made a test with your script and it retrieves all the emails except for the ones that are part of a group, it only shows the group email address, different from the UI that you can see those email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

From your following reply,

> Yes, groups are also included along with individual emails

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
guestList.forEach(function(guest){
  invitees.push([event_title,guest.getEmail()]);
});
```

#### To:

```
guestList.forEach(function (guest) {
  var email = guest.getEmail();
  if (email.includes("googlegroups.com")) {
    try {
      GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(email).getUsers().forEach(function (user) {
        invitees.push([event_title, user.getEmail()]);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message); // If an error occurs, you can see it in the log.
    }
  } else {
    invitees.push([event_title, email]);
  }
});
```

#### Note:

- When you have no permission for retrieving the users in the group, an error like `You do not have permission to view the member list for the group` occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [getGroupByEmail(email)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/groups-app#getGroupByEmail(String))

### Added:

From your following reply,

> what I meant was that guestList only returns 5 emails instead of 18 that I can see on calendar, none of the 5 emails have googlegroups.com

Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, for example, I guessed that your account might be in Google Workspace and the email of the group might be created with your domain. If my understanding is correct, the email of the group might not be `@googlegroups.com`. But, this is just my guess. If my guess is correct, how about the following sample script?

By the way, in this case, you are required to have permission for retrieving the users from the group. Please be careful about this.

#### From:

```
guestList.forEach(function(guest){
  invitees.push([event_title,guest.getEmail()]);
});
```

#### To:

```
var obj = GroupsApp.getGroups().reduce((o, e) => (o[e.getEmail()] = e, o), {});
guestList.forEach(function (guest) {
  var email = guest.getEmail();
  if (obj[email]) {
    try {
      obj[email].getUsers().forEach(function (user) {
        invitees.push([event_title, user.getEmail()]);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message);
    }
  } else {
    invitees.push([event_title, email]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that ```guestList``` only returns 5 emails instead of 18 that I can see on calendar, none of the 5 emails have ```googlegroups.com```

Comment: @PriyankaJ Now, I have one more guess for your situation. Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, for example, I guessed that your account might be in Google Workspace and the email of the group might be created with your domain. If my understanding is correct, the email of the group might not be `@googlegroups.com`. For this, I added one more modified script. Please confirm it. But, this is just my guess. If my guess is not correct, I apologize again.

Comment: @PriyankaJ As additional information. I thought that each email can be checked using the method of `getGroupByEmail`. But, in this case, all emails are required to be checked. So, I proposed the method using the above modification. But, if you are required to check all emails using `getGroupByEmail`, please tell me.